# How can i filter in sales order grid magento 2?

Tags: magento2, di, order-grid, ui

While i am using same code for filter it's working but i have break other grid  like customer,invoice,cms page and get error **"Not registered handle cms_page_listing_data_source"**

While i have moved di.xml file in etc/ folder grid filter not working. any have idea about.

I have created di.xml file in etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

FIlter collection in

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;


class Collection extends OriginalCollection {
    protected $_authSession;
    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,

        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
    ) {
        $this->_authSession = $authSession;
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager);
    }

    protected function _renderFiltersBefore() {
        $user = $this->_authSession->getUser();
        $joinTable = $this->getTable('sales_order');
        $this->getSelect()->where('stockist_id = ' . $user->getId());
        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sagar,

Not registered handle cms_page_listing_data_source

Can you send me code of CMS grid

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom module or already exit its not issue.
In etc folder di.xml created plugin

```
        <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter">
                <plugin name="bindStoreManagerSearch" type="Namespace\Module_name\Plugin\Grid\Search\StoreManagerSearch" sortOrder="1" />
        </type>
```

Create StoreManagerSearch.php file in plugin folder

```
        <?php

            namespace Namespace\Module_name\Plugin\Grid\Search;

            class StoreManagerSearch {

                public function aroundApply(
                    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter $subject, 
                    callable $proceed, 
                    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection, 
                    \Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter
                ){  
                    $result = $proceed($collection, $filter);

                    if($collection->getConnection()->tableColumnExists($collection->getMainTable(), 'store_manager')) {

                        $collection->getSelect()->orWhere('`main_table`.stockist_id = ?', "your_custom_id"); 

                        $parentTable = null;

                        if($collection->getMainTable() == 'sales_order_grid') {

                            $parentTable = 'sales_order';

                        } else if($collection->getMainTable() == 'sales_invoice_grid') {

                            $parentTable = 'sales_invoice';

                        } else if($collection->getMainTable() == 'sales_shipment_grid') {

                            $parentTable = 'sales_shipment';

                        } else if($collection->getMainTable() == 'sales_creditmemo_grid') {

                            $parentTable = 'sales_creditmemo';
                        } else {

                            $parentTable = 'sales_order';
                        }

                        if($parentTable && $collection->getConnection()->tableColumnExists($parentTable, 'store_manager')) {

                            $collection->getSelect()->join(
                                ['sm' => $parentTable],
                                "sm.entity_id = main_table.entity_id",
                                []
                            ); 

                            $collection->getSelect()->orWhere('`sm`.store_manager = ?', $filter->getValue());  
                        } 
                    } 

                    return $result;
                }
            }
```

Comment: i have tried your solution but StoreManagerSearch.php file not called.